# Document List menu not opening

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, editing-menu

I have a document library that is generating some jquery errors when I am opening the library.

The documents open up as they are supposed to but some libraries in the site are generating the below errors:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"[Learn More] Strategic%20Management.aspx
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 Strategic%20Management.aspx:685:1
Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead. mquery.js:1:16253
unreachable code after return statement sp.ribbon.js:2:177246
```

I am trying to click on the `...` but nothing is happening.

[image]

[image]

This seems to happen when I use used the View 'All Documents'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is that your site is on HTTPS but you are loading jQuery from HTTP. That causes this error as this is mixed content and potentially unsafe. Change the link to jQuery to use HTTPS instead and the error will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I need to modify the master page with sharepoint designer to switch to HTTPS? Or is there another method?

Comment: No, you have to change the link to jQuery from HTTP to HTTPS. http**s**://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js instead of http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

Comment: Yes, but there isn't any custom code on the page. I don't know from where I can modify it.

Comment: But threre is jQuery somewhere. Could be on the masterpage or in a Script Editor Webpart or Content Editor Webpart. But somewhere you are loading jQuery and this link has to be changed. Alternatively you can deactivate the mixed-content check in your browser. But that you will have to do on each and every browser that is accessing the site. So it would be simpler just to change the link to jQuery.

Comment: almost there...if you are unable to find the location check in developer tool, in Scripts tab you will find your jquery link..check from which location it is coming from

Comment: Thanks.. fixed it! It seems the document library web-part by default is using the non-ssl setting. all I had to do was insert https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js in the JS Link text-box in the document library web-part settings.